# Trick for opening Powershell at open directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcuts

If you type "cmd" into the address bar of a window it opens the command line at that directory.  Is there a way to do this same with powershell, thus saving you navigating to some deep recess of your file table?

Comment: Have you tried that with PowerShell? I believe it was added with PowerShell v3...

Comment: On Windows 7 type powershell in the address bar ...

Comment: David, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks guys.

Comment: You can also drag-and-drop a folder onto the PowerShell console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added PowerShell to my shell so if I right click on a folder or the background of a folder I get an "Open PowerShell Here" option that opens PowerShell in the selected or current directory.

Simply add these registry keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"
```

Should be able to paste the above into a text file and change the extension to .reg and just import it.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Have my checkmarks.

Comment: Added another key to also work with backgrounds of library folders (such as Documents, Photos, etc)